# Change emacs keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have a UK keyboard and this is setup and functioning on Ubuntu 21.04 with all of my apps. When I open emacs inside a terminal using `emacs -nw` it also correctly used the gb keyboard layout. However when opening emacs (27.2, built from repo) in a new frame from a call to `emacs` or clicking on the shortcut, it switches to a us keyboard layout. I am unable to get it to use a qwerty-gb layout.

I have tried setting in my config/calling interactively:

```
(setq quail-keyboard-layout 'pc105-uk)
```

However whatever I choose doesn't appear to have any impact.

I have also tried interactively calling `set-input-method british`. This has had some help in the shift+3 is now '£' instead of '#'. However other keys such as my '#' come out as '\'.

Please could I have some help?

Comment: Are you really using quail? It is not the default, and if you’re only typing English text it is never necessary.

Comment: I don't think I am using it. I was trying to set that variable because I got the impression from other threads I had seen that it might do what I wanted.

Comment: What does `C-h I RET` tell you?

Comment: And for that matter, what about `C-h L RET`?

Comment: Two answers because I normally use spacemacs, but I am trying to fix this problem on a default (no config) setup in the hopes if it being clearer.

C-h I RET:
When I start emacs with an empty .emacs.d, it says 'No input method is activated now.'

C-h L RET:
Default: 'English language environment [...]'

Spacemacs, despite saying '(default current choice)' tells me about Burmese. I think this is a nonsensical answer.

Edit: gah my newlines have disappeared, sorry that is ugly to read.

Comment: Yea, I have no idea if Spacemacs tampers with anything. With no input method activated, and the English language environment selected, everything should just work correctly. Try running `M-x set-language-environment` and entering UTF-8. Maybe that will work better. If it does, then you can run `M-x customize-variable` and select `current-language-environment`. Use the resulting form to save this variable so that it keeps that value next time you start Emacs.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't help matters. But thank you for trying!

Comment: The only other thing to try then is to start Emacs with `-Q` and see if the problem persists. If it doesn’t then the problem is somewhere in your Emacs configuration.

Comment: The problem persists.

Comment: Well, that narrows it down. It’s either a problem with your operating system, or an Emacs bug.

Comment: Ah I have luckily stumbled onto solution using setxkbmap. I will edit the Q with the solution.

Comment: You should instead add an answer and (provided it works for you :-) ) you should accept it (after the appropriate waiting interval). That way, future visitors know that the question *has* been answered. Editing the question with the answer does not do that.

Comment: This long comment chain signals a likely problem with the question. Comments can be deleted at any time - questions need to stand on their own. Please incorporate whatever helps from the comments into the question, and clarify the question to ask what you really want. You can also post an answer to your own question, and you can even accept it as the right answer if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by explicitly calling `setxkbmap -model pc105 -layout gb` in the terminal before opening emacs. I have added this to my .bashrc

The following thread was my inspiration for trying this:
[Unable to change keyboard layout in EXWM/Emacs27.1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62185/unable-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-exwm-emacs27-1)

Comment: It would be extremely useful to know what OS you’re using, and how your other applications had the correct keyboard layout if X Windows didn’t. On Linux, all applications ultimately ask X Windows to translate keycodes into characters; this includes Emacs.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04. Unfortunately I can't answer the second question, as I don't know about these things. It is a relatively new Ubuntu installation and I had just put all the language settings to english - gb and everything except emacs worked out of the box.